# Can a moderator select an answer?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I'd like to know if moderators can select my answer or do I have to wait for the person who posted the question to select it?

I answered this question [Where do I register .sh domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/27122/10527) my answer was up voted 3 times. The question was

> I want to register a personal domain with sh extension. Where to
>   register? I didn't find any registrar. I will use this for my personal
>   blog and portfolio. I didn't have any organisation or any company. I
>   reside in India if it helps

And I answered with http://www.nic.sh/registrars.html which lists all the registrars for the .SH TLD. Now he's asking me in the comments why the price is so high.

Can it be flagged to have moderators review it to select the answer or do I just need to wait it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the question asker can accept an answer.

Note: It's not necessarily in your interest to see the question closed ASAP - your answer will likely continue to receive upvotes so long as the question remains open (answers to questions with an accepted answer tend to receive upvotes at a much lower rate from my experience).